# How to take Apple System Font file?

Tags: ios, fonts, system-font

Currently I am working on a certain app for Apple platform and will add Apple Sign-in on it.

On the [design requirement](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/) there are certain rules for when we made our custom button for it. One of it is: using Apple System Font.

So, then I search what is "Apple Sytem Font" and the found this: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/

From what I understand (cmiiw), is that Apple has sets of font listed there which I can choose from one of them and use it on my apps.

The problem in here is that my app use a some framework and tools for the UI, which need the fonts file to be available locally on the machine. Because it will be used to build the assets into the app data.

So, the question is how can I have the .ttf file from the those list?

They said to use Apple Font Book to download it, but I don't know how do I possibly get the .ttf file from it. From what I understand Apple Font Book is like Bitstream Font Navigator from Corel, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS system font is **San Francisco**

https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

You should be able to download the variations from that link and install them on your "build the assets" system.

Comment: so, this list of fonts https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/ is not the system font from Apple? or those "was" system fonts of Apple? And when they say "System-Font" which font they think about (current System Font or also previous system-font) ?

Comment: When developing for iOS (and Mac), one generally uses the **SystemFont** rather than a font-by-name... partly for consistency, partly for ease of dynamic type usage, partly so your app uses the *current* system font when it changes, etc. Might be worth watching the WWDC19 session video from that link...

Comment: ah, I just downloaded the font from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ , the file is a .dmg file, not .ttf. How do I get the .ttf?

Comment: `.dmg` is a Disk Image file... just open it and double-click the package. It will install the fonts. You can find them in `/System/Library/Fonts`

Comment: yep, actually inside the .dmg file only has .otf files, so I only need to convert it to .ttf.  But, yes, it works. Thank you